# Data fetching is very slow when placing a limit of more than 100

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

In Orientdb when I am running queries on console, it by default is taking limit as 20.
But when I want all my records in my database, I have to put a limit like `limit 500` then it's taking a lot of time for 1000 records which is around 6 minutes!
Someone please provide me some solution for such a case.
And also, can we change the default limit 20 to a desired limit?

Comment: please start by posting the query along with your db structure

Comment: For the request about default limit, you can see it with 'properties' command, in console, as documented in http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Console-Command-Properties.html. It is currently hardcoded in source code OConsoleDatabaseApp.java as properties.put("limit", "20"), but, while running console, you can change it with : set limit <limit> . The value -1 means unlimited

Comment: Do you have indexes on the Where fields?